# Change Theme Colour in Android App

Tags: android, coding-style, themes

I am currently trying to get a common user experience in Gingerbread as well as Ice Cream Sandwich. The main part is about theme colours.

In Gingerbread the main colour was green, ICS enforces blue.

Is it possible to override this global colour (green / black) by a given colour only in this one app?

Thanks,
Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to create a custom `style`. Take a look a this guide  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html and at this interesting post http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html